# Importing an existing heroku Ruby project into Aptana Studio 3

Tags: heroku, aptana

I'm starting to use Aptana Studio 3. I have a project on heroku and want to start working on it in Aptana. I have been unable to find any documentationn on how to do this. It seems that if I want to create a new project and then deploy it to heroku, that works (the deployment wizard requires that I give the project a name, but that shouldn't apply to an existing application).

I can create a Ruby project by pointing to the heroku git repository URI with the project creation wizard, but it doesn't let me deploy. I get the following message in the terminal:

[2015]: git push heroku master
fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Aptana add a origin git remote point to heroku, but when you click on deploy button it call command "git push heroku master"

easy way to deploy is just rename origin remote to heroku.

console at your project and put command `git remote rename origin heroku`

it work well for me,
have fun :)

Comment: Actually, the problem was even simpler. Instead of trying to import the project from heroku, I just had to find the directory I was working in on my file system and promote it to a project. That did the job.